# Typescript - what's the difference between Obj[] and [Obj]

Tags: javascript, typescript

let assume I have an interface like below.

```
interface Obj {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

If I declare a new variable in these 2 ways

1)

```
const obj: Obj[];
```

2. 

```
const obj: [Obj]
```

What's the difference of these 2 type declaration?

Comment: `Obj[]` is an array of any number of `Obj` elements; `[Obj]` is a tuple containing *exactly one* `Obj` element.  See the linked question/answer for more information.